# mysqldump on replica for backup and GTID

Tags: mysql, backup, mysqldump

I use replica instead source database for backups. After enabling GTID mode I am not sure how I should use mysqldump to make correct dump. This backup is for source recovery of course.

`mysqldump --single-transaction db > dump.sql`

or

`mysqldump --single-transaction --set-gtid-purged=OFF db > dump.sql`

?

MySQL version is 8.0.

Comment: Which mysql version are you using?

Comment: I use mysql 8.0

Comment: specifying the exact version (major + minor) is needed. Officials docs states that mixing --single-transaction and --set-gtid-purged could cause inconsistencies.